# how to relate two table by after insert trigger in sql server 2008r2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger such that if i am inserting some values in 1st table than the two field of the 2nd table automatically updated. 
case is that i have a table in which i'm storing user details

First Table

`1st name   | last name   |   userId   |   password   |   adress   |  email`

and 2nd login table which have two field

Second Table

`userId   |   password`

now i want if i change value of password in 1st table is automatically reflect in the 2nd table what is the query for that.

Comment: You have the data in the first table. Why would you duplicate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this....

```
   CREATE TRIGGER trgTest ON Test
   FOR INSERT
   AS
  INSERT Test2
  (Id, value)
  SELECT Id, Value 
  FROM Inserted
```

or if you're using stored procedures you can easily manage this

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Insert
 @Value varchar(10)
 AS
 insert into table1 (...,...) values (@value,...)
 insert into table2 (...,...) values (@value,...)
```

Comment: I also want to know if same process i wanted again when we update the your Test table than it also reflect in the Test2 table

Answer (score 1):

as long as the userid and password for the second table are mapped as foreign keys to the first table, i think you should be able to set "on update cascade" on the rows

Comment: If you don't truly need to use triggers I would probably go with this approach. I don't know that there's a definite answer for which way is better but this would definitely seem cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You've mostly answered your own question, Prakash. Check out the [MSDN documentation on triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for the specific syntax you need. Jon's comment in regard to the duplication of data points out that your schema is somewhat denormalized so you may want to take a look at changing that unless it's required for your situation.

From MSDN

```
   INSERT INTO auditEmployeeData
     (audit_log_type,
     audit_emp_id,
     audit_emp_bankAccountNumber,
     audit_emp_salary,
     audit_emp_SSN)
     SELECT 'NEW',
        ins.emp_id,
        ins.emp_bankAccountNumber,
        ins.emp_salary,
        ins.emp_SSN
     FROM inserted ins
```

Comment: i find this CREATE TRIGGER xyz
ON dbo.UDetail
after insert 
as
insert into dbo.login (UserName,Pwd,Role)
values(new.UserId,new.Pwd,'user');                                   but i don't know why this new is used and i'm getting error:multipart identifier  new.userId and new.pwd not found

Comment: For MSSQL that should be 'inserted' not 'new'. I think the example you found probably aliased inserted as new. Edited the post with an example.